# PHP Pagination Showing Error

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have created a pagination for my website and It shows an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in Foldername on line 29

Here's the code I've been working on:

```
<?php

    $count_query = mysql_query("SELECT NULL FROM posts");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($count_query);

    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {

        $page = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$_GET['page']);

    } else {

        $page = 1;

    }

    $perPage = 10;
    $lastPage = ceil($count / $perPage);

    if ($page < 1) {

        $page = 1;

    } else if ($page > $lastPage) {

        $page = $lastPage;

    }

    $limit = "LIMIT " .($page -1)"$perPage.","$perPage";

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY postNum DESC $limit");

    if ($lastPage != 1) {

        if ($page != $lastPage) {
            $next = $page + 1;
            $pagination .= '<a href="foldername/?page='.$next.'" class="pagerRight">Next</a>';
        }

        if ($page != 1) {
            $prev = $page - 1;
            $pagination .= 'foldername/?page='.$prev.'" class="pagerLeft">Prev</a>';
        }

    }

?>
```

The line 29 is: `$limit = "LIMIT " .($page -1)"$perPage.","$perPage";`

Comment: Yeah, definitely something wrong with `$limit = "LIMIT " .($page -1)"$perPage.","$perPage";`

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. You also have some highly suspicious code here to inject the pagination variable, something that seems unusually convoluted.

Comment: Yep I do know that but do you have any Idea what Is the problem In that piece of code???

Comment: `echo $limit = "LIMIT " .($page -1)"$perPage.","$perPage";` and you'll see what's being passed through. You'll need to fix your concatenates.

Comment: This syntax error would be easier to figure out if we knew what you wanted `$limit` to be.

Comment: Btw, you've a typo `OREDER`

Comment: @Fred-ii- that was a typing mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and change

```
$limit = "LIMIT " .($page -1)"$perPage.","$perPage";
```

with

```
$limit = "LIMIT ".($page -1)*$perPage.",".$page*$perPage."";
```

This solution will multiply $page-1 for 10 (i've seen your code) limiting paging -1 * 10 to page *10

Example:

Page 1:

LIMIT 0, 10
Page 2:
LIMIT 10,20
etc...

Edit:

Try change

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts OREDER BY postNum DESC $limit");
```

with:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY postNum DESC ".$limit."");
```

Corrected OREDER with ORDER and used correct chain (dot)

Comment: That does work but it shows all of the posts insted of paginating it by 10.

Comment: Still the same results :(

Comment: The `OREDER` was a typing mistake!

Comment: run that query on phpmyadmin or similar, it works? if yes try to see (with a var dump) what $limit got inside, if is it ok, try to loop the data to show the posts, i do not see that code on your question

Comment: Is there any other way to do It cause I have a lot of data to show with a lot of div's

Comment: You can limit those with Javascript maybe (on front-end), count element of an item, if more then 10 you can erase some

Comment: I tried the loop, It It shows nothing not even the posts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66762/discussion-between-marco-mura-and-arqetech).